# 'Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V' stucked on 20%

Tags: powershell

I have executed below command :

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V | Select-Object InstallState
```

It got stucked on 20%

[image]

I waited for 30 mins but still no response.

Any specific reason and how I should I get rid of this ?

OS : W2K12R2

Powershell Version :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is odd, and something I've never had happen, but may indicate something is amiss on your computer you are working on. You also don't say what OS version you are seeing this on, i.e., WS2008 - 2019.

Anyway, try a few different ways to see what the results are.

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name '*hyper-v' | Select-Object -Property *
Name                      : Hyper-V
DisplayName               : Hyper-V
Description               : Hyper-V provides ... 
                            virtualized ...
                            simultaneously.
Installed                 : False
InstallState              : Available
FeatureType               : Role
Path                      : Hyper-V
Depth                     : 1
DependsOn                 : {}
Parent                    : 
ServerComponentDescriptor : ServerComponent_HyperV
SubFeatures               : {}
SystemService             : {vmms}
Notification              : {}
BestPracticesModelId      : Microsoft/Windows/Hyper-V
EventQuery                : Virtualization.Events.xml
PostConfigurationNeeded   : False
AdditionalInfo            : {MajorVersion, Mino...


(Get-WindowsFeature -Name '*hyper-v').Installed
False

(Get-WindowsFeature -Name '*hyper-v').InstallState
Available

Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V | Select-Object InstallState
                                                              InstallState
                                                              ------------
                                                              Available

Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V | Select-Object InstallState | ft -HideTableHeaders
                                                              Available

Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V | Select-Object InstallState | ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
                                                              Available
```

Also, what is the reason for using Out-String, when the values are string by default?

Comment: OS version is W2K12R2

Comment: No reason for Out-String. If I execute  only First part of command still it get stucked. Similar result for the command you posted in answer

Comment: My response is on W2K12R2 as well, and tested on v4+ and v5.1+ (2012R2-2019) successfully.  I have no server with the PSBuild you have and that build is superseded by 5.1, so no longer available for download. At this point I'd upgrade that PS version or fire up procmon and monitor as you try again, to see if you can discern any oddity. Is this happening with any feature your insert? Just curious?

Comment: Lastly, any single feature notwithstanding, if you run Get-WindowsFeature alone do you see the same issue? If so, then something is wrong with your installed environment.

Comment: I tried with only Get-WindowsFeature only. Same result.